# The use of the future tense for describing one's usual routines

Tags: modal-verbs, future, aspect, modality

In this [video](https://youtu.be/KYaP3yCyHRY) at 5 minute and 50 seconds, for reasons unknown to me, a speaker used the future tense for describing his usual routine.

> So in the assistance portion of my workout, I will choose row variations that by nature are a little lighter.

Why didn't the person say "I choose row variations"? Does the use of the future simple add some sort of emphasis, like his habit cannot be changed, and no matter what, he will choose the row variations?

Comment: Do any of the online dictionaries (coverage of modals is much better than it was say 50 years ago) give a usage that seems to correspond? ('Habitual practice' seems close, but the examples given refer to the resigned 'boys _will_ be boys' complaint). Perhaps it's just present-simple-avoidance (it often sounds weak).

Comment: Never assume that *will VERB* can only ever indicate futurity. English modals never do just one thing alone

Comment: It's just the "non-past" (not necessarily "future", which doesn't actually exist as a distinct tense in English) version of the "habitual action" - *On Sundays **I would / I'd** go to church*. But to the extent there's any "nuance of meaning" to the choice in the example as cited, I think he's slightly emphasising the fact that because those choices (of row variations) aren't *exactly* "here and now, current", we can assume he often makes ***different*** choices on different occasions.

Comment: Is that non-past is somehow different form the present simple?

Comment: Why would the use of *will* not be appropriate here? He's not choosing anything at the current moment, but is instead talking both about what he has done before habitually and what he will continue to do in the future, also habitually.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope "Present simple" is not a finite-verb inflection in English morphology. The only two finite-verb inflections possible in present-day English are ***past*** (eg: *She spoke*) and ***non-past*** (eg: *She speaks*). All other times, aspects, and moods are indicated analytically (ie, by adding other words) rather than synthetically (ie, by morphological inflection).

Comment: @JasonBassford Because it means habitually, not at some instant in the future.

Comment: @tchrist There is absolutely nothing unidiomatic about talking about something you do habitually and will *continue* to do in the future. In one interpretation, something that is habitual is without a tense at all. It's simply *always* done. *When I take the garbage out, I will always replace it with an empty bag.* That implies, past, present, *and* future. And while the sentence would mean the same thing if *will* were dropped, it doesn't ***have*** to be.